# Internet Explorer Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have a page tab quiz application on my facebook page. It has 2 phps: 
**index.php:** like-gate, permission requests and quiz questions (within a form), these works fine in all browsers. 
**processor.php**: processes the form, uploads an image:

> $photo_upload = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
>
> > 'source' => '@' . './images/userimg.jpg',
> >     'message' => $message,
> >     )
> >     );

Everything works in Chrome, Mozilla, Safari. But in IE i get this error on processor.php:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in .../php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1128

It seems like that it loses access token or the token expires after submitting the form in IE.

I've tried the login url below but it only works in Chrome or Mozilla when user closes his browser. In IE clicking on the login link loads the same page with the login link.

> $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

*Why does IE handle access tokens other way than the other browsers?*

Any solution appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This will help you. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-set-third-party-cookies-with-iframe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does IE handle access tokens other way than the other browsers?

It does not, of course.

More likely is that it does not accept cookies necessary to pass on the required information.

“Third party cookie problem” is your keyword.